# HNSC, SSL and Mixed Content

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, ssl, host-named

I have setup a Multi-Tenancy Farm and everything seems to be working fine except for the fact that I'm getting Mixed Content when viewing my Site through SSL.  The SSL is being offloaded to the load balancer.

I initially setup my Web Application with No Host Header on Port 80 and created my HNSC without SSL. Ex: test.sharepoint.com

I then extended my HNSC for SSL using this command
Set-SPSiteUrl -Identity $site.Url -Url https://test.sharepoint.com -Zone Internet

This all seems fine but again when I login to the HNSC site i see these errors in my console.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://test.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://test.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/blank.js?rev=ZaOXZEobVwykPO9g8hq%2F8A%3D%3D'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
start.js?rev=XFhC2yBo1NQ183GJoVt%2ByA%3D%3D:1 
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://test.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://test.sharepoint.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=OlE2pnmvhKwrlnyNyHlU0DG…q8kUMFW6luTJf9MpfjN8_ttt4hRXMWUbt_YhigcyzatfRl3LskVFhg0&t=ffffffffb53e74b8'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
start.js?rev=XFhC2yBo1NQ183GJoVt%2ByA%3D%3D:1
```

...

I'm wondering what i have to do to fix this issue.  Any help is appreciated!

Adam

Comment: did you try different browser?

Comment: Yes I've tried Chrome, IE and Firefox .. all reporting the same issues.

Comment: I'm no network guy, but I thought if you were offloading ssl to the load balancer, you didn't need to ssl the Sharepoint servers

Comment: and is the load balancer using sticky sessions

Comment: I'm no network guy either but I thought you at least had to setup the URL mappings within SharePoint but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score -1):

Mostly it is related to the Browser you are using, before their was an issue with chrome.
Also what is URL for the default zone, are you using Http or Https? May be that's your issue.

have a look on these.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/083dfb43-3a3f-437c-b10a-3554fa8cac54/sharepoint-2013-ms-office-web-apps-owaps-google-chrome-mixed-content-error?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: I even changed the Default zone of my HNSC to be https and no change.  I was mainly curious if i needed to setup the Web Application as SSL by default but i wanted to confirm there is no other way to fix this first before i did that.

Comment: what are the AAM settings for the web App?

Comment: I didn't set any additional AAM's for the web app... could that be my issue?  There is currently just the default zone at port 80 currently set.

Comment: Actually the web application is setup on port 81 as I had another web application that was currently using port 80.  I assume that isn't part of my issue as everything is working except for this Mixed Content issue I can't resolve.

Comment: do you have any customization on the site? looks JS file loading from the http....check this to understand it http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/https-mixed-content-in-ie8.aspx

Comment: No this is a brand new setup with no customization.

Comment: you have your SSL at NLB level not on the server, correct? do you have your root level site collection?

Comment: Yes the SSL is setup at the NLB level and not on the server.
Yes I have created the root level site collection created using the servername and port 81.